# While slicing in python why end+1/end-1 other than end?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Suppose `s="mrunal"`

I want to print `run`

for that I am doing `print(s[1:4])`

But in python why `print(s[1:3])` is not available.

Simply I want to tell that why `end` in slicing is not that index which we want as last character?

```
s="mrunal"
```

index 0 = "m"

index 1 = "r"

index 2 = "u"

index 3 = "n"

index 4 = "a"

index 5 = "l"

here index for `"n"` is 3. Why end index is not same as `s[1:3]`? Why it is not inclusive? why it uses exclusive?

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/4152153) answer, it may clear your doubts about slicing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: Half open intervals are easier to reason about. For example, `s[1:4] + s[4:] == s`.

Comment: `foo[0:5]` gives you up to 5 characters. Slices are often calculated values. `foo[n:n+2]` gives you up to 2. `foo[foo:foo+bar]` would give you 0 characters if `bar` is zero. Its usually the most natural way to do things.

Comment: @dcg @TomMyddeltyn It not providing my question's answer ```why it is?```

Comment: @tdelaney but why exclusive? is any _specific reason_ for doing that exclusive?

Comment: I did. Its because adding X to the first index gives you X characters.

Comment: Consider other uses, `for index in range(5)` - it would be weird if this enumerated 6 things. `while index < len(sequence)` - note the _less than_ which keeps the index from overflowing the sequence. `mylist[len(mylist)]` is in an index error. A list's final element is `len - 1`.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a great answer, but when dealing with indexing sequences, the upper bound is often *exclusive*, meaning it doesn't include the index itself.

Why? I've always assumed it was because the last index of a sequence is one less than the size, which let's you use the size as the upper bound without needing to offset it by 1:

```
s[1:] == s[1:len(s)]
```

Also note that the behavior is the same with `range` as well, where the upper bound of it is exclusive.

This also isn't specific to Python. Many languages use exclusive upper bounds; especially when dealing with indexing of sequences. It's a good thing to expect unless you read otherwise.

Comment: This is I think the answer to the actual question: the OP is asking _why_ it works like this, not _how_ it works, so the duplicate isn't relevant. The answer is this - for consistency with `range()`, which in turn does it that way for consistency with older programming languages, for the reasons you laid out.

Comment: @Carcigenicate But why it does not take ```end``` as it is even if starts from zero. As I am shown example why end+1 not direct end?

Comment: @MRUNALMUNOT I tried to address that under "why". The last index is `size - 1`, so making it exclusive saves you from needing to subtract 1. It's the same with `for` loops in other languages using `<`. If you want to iterate an array by index in C/C++/Java, the for loop will look like `for (int i = 0; i < arr_len; i++)`. It uses `<` so that you don't need to `- 1`. It's the same idea. `<` is defining an exclusive upper bound. I'll incorporate that into my answer when I get a break.

Answer (score -2):

Edit:

Python, starts counting from 0. This means that if you need the first letter, you write 0. The second letter 1 and so on

```
s="mrunal"

index 0 = "m"

index 1 = "r"

index 2 = "u"

index 3 = "n"

index 4 = "a"

index 5 = "l"
```

This means you will need to take the second letter (index 1) to the fourth letter (index 4)

Comment: Here as you explained for character ```"n" ```index is 3. Why as it is index it is not accepting?

Comment: The last letter you type (index 4) is not counted

Comment: By the way, fun fact: 
```s="mrunal"

print(s[0 : : 2])```

Comment: My code above in comment prints "mrunal" In skips of 2
"mua"

Comment: so, Why it is exclusive, not inclusive?

Comment: I'm not sure. This is how Python works